# Migrate linode to google cloud platform

Tags: migration, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, linode

I currently have an application running on a ubuntu server on linode. I wonder if I can move the settings and files to the google cloud platform without having to reconfigure and install everything again.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate VM with Cloudendure[1] service to Google Cloud Platform free of charge [2]. Keep in mind that is limited to the following operating systems [3]:

Windows:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit
- Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit
- Microsoft Windows Server 2016 64 bit
- Windows desktop operating systems are not supported.

Linux:

- SUSE Linux (SLES) 11 or above
- Debian Linux 8
- Kali Linux 2.0
- Ubuntu 12.04 or above
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 5.0 or above
- CentOS 6.0 or above
- Oracle Linux 6.0 or above

[1] https://www.cloudendure.com/

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/migrating-vms-compute-engine#costs

[3] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/migrating-vms-compute-engine#limitations